# Finding where id or class was used in a Marionette application - reversed reverse engineering

Tags: backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools, marionette

I'm debugging a huge application. How would I figure out which display or render an id or class was used? It's actually the other way around rather than us right-clicking on an element then doing an Inspect Element.

Problem is that I've been opening so many modals and inspecting the DOM manually and hoping to see the id or class. Eventually I'll find it but this is crazy! I'm not doing it right.

Comment: Have you used the [Marionette Inspector](http://marionettejs.com/inspector/)? It might help you there.

Comment: Also if you know a certain element has a certain id or class or attribute, and you just need to find it, you can find it by selector from console.

Comment: Yura, I have Marionette inspector installed but I will be honest, I've only used it for 3 times and only stayed on that screen for like a minute. I'll try it again.